# How to solve an issue with my IP getting repeatedly banned due to incorrect SSH login attempts?

Tags: ssh, login, authentication

I recently upgraded my laptop to Ubuntu 21.10. I do not know if it is related, but I started having the following issue after the upgrade:

At work I connect to a cluster via SSH. For this I use key-based login. Since upgrading Ubuntu, my laptop IP (which is fixed in the work-LAN) has started getting banned from SSH login repeatedly. This only happens sometimes (~4x in the last 2 weeks) and I don't know why.

The cluster-admin (who already lifted the ban a couple of times) told me, that my IP is getting banned due to SSH login attempts with incorrect user-name. I assume these were password-based login-attempts, since the user-name should not matter for key-based login, from what I have read (though the admin was unable to tell me, if the login-attempts were password- or key-based).

Notably, the incorrect user-name is the one I use on my local system (from which I log into the cluster) and which I use on Linux-systems at home (on the cluster I have a different user-name).

Given that I use key-based login to access the cluster, I currently *suspect* that the issue is caused by local process trying to SSH into the cluster with incorrect credentials in the background. However, I do not know *which* process is the culprit and/or how to confirm this. I do not even know where to start looking.

I am currently considering resetting/deleting my complete key-chain and all credentials and restarting "from zero" (though I am scared I might miss something and thus it would not solve it). Perhaps anyone has a better suggestion? I am clutching at straws right now ...

**EDIT 1 - replying to comments:**

This is the SSH command I use to login to the cluster using key-based authentication:

```
ssh -X CLUSTER_USERNAME@CLUSTER_HOSTNAME
```

I am currently do not have anything in `.ssh/config` (i.e. the file does not exist).

Comment: Please include details about how you use `ssh`. What command you actually run and what your `.ssh/config` contains

Comment: "the user-name should not matter for key-based login" – Incorrect. The SSH server does not check every possible user's `authorized_keys`. The client specifies the user it wants to authenticate as and *then* the right `authorized_keys` file is used. // For a possible solution check this SU question: [How to make ssh log in as the right user](https://superuser.com/q/64996/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thank you for the clarification. I updated my post to include the SSH command that I use for key-based login. It is with the correct user-name.
@Panki I did not previously use `.ssh/config`. I now added the following to it:
```
Host *.CLUSTER_DOMAIN
    User CLUSTER_USERNAME
```
My hope is that this should make the process the is causing this, use the correct login. Question: I also use SFTP from Nautilus file-explorer - does this also set the default user for SFTP?

Comment: You can create an alias (or function or shellscript) that contains your command line to log in with the correct user name. That way you can avoid using the wrong user-name.

Comment: @sudodus That is what I am already doing. But thanks any for the suggestion.